# Testing button is disabled while form is invalid

Tags: angular, testing

I have a template driven form

```
<form #submissionForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let choice of question.choices">
        <input
          ngModel
          required
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          value="{{ choice.id }}"
          name="questionChoices[]"
          id="choice-{{ choice.id }}"
        >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="choice-{{ choice.id }}">
          {{ choice.label }}
        </label>
      </div>
    <button
      [disabled]="submissionForm.invalid"
      type="submit"
      class="btn btn-primary">
     </button>
```

And then a test:

```
it('should disable submit button until form is valid', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(QuestionComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.question = mockData.question[0].multipleChoice;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('[type="submit"]').disabled).toBeTruthy();
});
```

My test fails with `Error: Expected false to be truthy.`

This works fine when actually running the app and visiting the page but when debugging via Karma in browser I see that the button is not disabled.  Is something wrong with my code or my test? (or both?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync) and [tick()](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-tick-function) in order to advance the (virtual) clock and to reach the time/moment the button gets the event that notify the form is valid.

```
it('should disable submit button until form is valid', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(QuestionComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.question = mockData.question[0].multipleChoice;
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('[type="submit"]').disabled).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Try this to see if it works.